# Service account shows up on login screen

Tags: 13.10, login, lightdm, users

I've manually created a service user account on my machine, and I'm surprised to see it on the Unity login screen. I searched this site and I've seen people had problems with this, but in those cases, the UID was above `minimum-uid` and the suggestion was to either change the uid or add the user to the `hidden-users` list. But my case is different.

The user account in question is:

```
mgsmtp:x:118:8::/opt/mgsmtp/:/bin/sh
```

UID = 118; GID = 8 (mail)

My `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` file is configured like this:

```
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

In my understanding, since the UID is below 500, it must not show up on the login screen. But it does anyway. I also don't understand why all the other service accounts don't show up then - they aren't listed in `hidden-users` either. I don't see the difference between my service account and all the others on the system.

Note that I have this service account for more than a year now, but it only showed up on the login screen after I upgraded to Saucy from Quantal. Before that, while I was using Quantal, it was correctly hidden.

Before using the `hidden-users` hack, I'd like to understand why it works like this.